# How to deal with equal fractions in polynomial quotient ring Q[x]

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

I have an equation $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{r}{s}$ in Q[x] with the known property that
the gcd of p and q is 1.

I would like to infer $r=p$ and $s=q$ but doubt that this is correct.
( I already know from CAS calculations that this conclusion is right in my special case )

My problem is that I cant prove just now that also the gcd of the expressions r and s
on the right side is 1.

Edit:

I give more details about the second case where I want to make this conclusion
as in this case I have on the right side no polynomial expression in x where from i can
deduce facts about the degree of the polynomials.

I this case I got a formula of this type
$$\frac{p_{n+1}}{q_{n+1}}=\frac{p_n+xq_n}{q_n-xp_n}$$
It has been quite formally deduced from the definition of the polynomial sequence. But at this stage I cant prove nothing about the degrees of the polynomials in the sequence. I know that the conclusion $p_{n+1}=p_n+xq_n$ is correct but dont know under what circumstances this conclusion is formally
proved.

Comment: Well, on this level of generality you can only say that $r=pf$ and $s=qf$ for some polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ and that $f=gcd(r,s)$. This follows easily from the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD. Or do you have some extra information about the fraction $r/s$ you have not mentioned yet? Anyway, what eclxactly is the question?

Comment: This question should be understood well before one encounters polynomials - it applies directly to rational numbers themselves. Recall equalities like $\frac{1}{1}=\frac{2}{2}=\frac{3}{3}=\cdots$. This is why we have the phrase "simplest form."

Comment: I have in one case additional information about the polynomial degrees. But I simply asked myself whether i could avoid the then necessary detailed case studies of the degrees depending on odd and even integers.

Answer (score 0):

You could have, for instance, $r = 2p$ and $s = 2q$. Based only on the fact that $\gcd(p,q) = 1$ (and $p/q = r/s$), you can't conclude anything about $\gcd(r,s)$.